# Unable to get MX Revolution work effectively in Mac

Tags: installation, mac, drivers, mouse

I installed Logitech control center. I set the settings as I want them in the Preferences.

However, only the Search button works. Expose and Dashboard do not work in the side buttons, for example.

I am interested which files the Control manager changes in my Mac Leopard. Perhaps, there is a text-file which would enable me to get the mouse working.

**Which files does Logitech's Control manager affect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth you don't need the Logitech Control Center installed but some features won't work (eg. scrolling with the thumb scroll wheel, "search" button). I personally have had issues with the software - at least it's no longer an APE application (but now it's an InputManager)

That said, as said by Dave Cheney the place to get Expose and Dashboard to work with buttons is in the Expose & Spaces Preference Pane.

The mount button numbers correspond as such (without the Control Center installed):

Mouse Button 5: The "forward" button
Mouse Button 4: The "back" button
Mouse Button 9: Rotate all the way forward on the thumb scroll wheel.
Mouse Button 11: Rotate all the way back on the thumb scroll wheel.
Mouse Button 13: Clicking the thumb scroll wheel

I suspect that with the Control Center installed left and right on the main scroll wheel and the "search" button will actually be recognized.

That said the Logitech Control Center settings are saved in `~/Library/Preferences/com.Logitech.Control.Center.Assignments.registry`.

Comment: It seems that I should uninstall Logitech drivers. It is hard for me to understand the file at the given Path.

Comment: Thank you! The uninstallation of the drivers solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`System Preferences` -> `Exposé & Spaces`

Have you set the mouse preferences in the second column of the Exposé section ?

Comment: I have the following settings now: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/mouseProblem.png . I am not sure which Mouse numbers should I use.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to figure it out from trial and error. You've mapped Mouse3 to the f9 action. Press f9, note the result, then try pressing every button you can find on the mouse until you get the same result. Rinse, repeat for the other buttons

Comment: @Dave: I have done that. I went all the buttons though for only one command. I could not see the difference. -- Do you have a list of what the buttons from 1 to about 40 mean? I could not find one.